# TableView and CollectionView: Adjust height of tableView and collectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-autolayout

I have a view controller, in which, i have tableView and collection view. I had set equal height for collectionView and tableView.

First Half is tableView and Second half is collection view.I have **one service calls** for **reloding tableview and collection view**.

So, I want to adjust height of collection view based on its datasource and then tableview automatically get adjusted based on collection view.

**Note**- TableView height is not depend on its datasource, only collection view height is depend on its data source.

//Collection view flow layout

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  return CGSizeMake((self.collectionView.frame.size.width/2)-4, 68);
}
```

//Current Screen Shot

[image]

Comment: You mean you want to make tableview height should dynamic (max half of screen height & should be decrease height  if items are less that that) & collectionView height should be adjust according that right? can you add screenshot for both condition will help to understand..

Comment: @Mukesh i have shared screen shot

Comment: @Mukesh i have,  shared screen shot and image, could u check it

Comment: Yes i am checking wait for sometime. You mean primarily you want to set equal height but is collection items are less i mean items are only 2 or 4 then collection view height should be get decreased accordingly & tableview should be increased?

Comment: @Mukesh yes, this actually i need, so what ever collection view, if less or more based on that height of table view should increase and decrease without any empty space in collection view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `auto layout` then you need to manage it by `height constraints` of both `tableView` & `collectionView` & if you are using frame then you need to set frame dynamic according to cells & cells height.

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{

[self adjustCollectionViewHeightForCollection:collectionView withNumberOfCollectionCells:dynamicCollectionCellArray.count];

  return dynamicCollectionCellArray.count;
}


    -(void) adjustCollectionViewHeightForCollection:(UICollectioView *)collectionView withNumberOfCollectionCells:(NSUInteger)numberOfCollectionCell{
      //Adjust CollectionView height constraint

    int height = kConstantCollectionCellHeight * (numberOfCollectionCell /2 + numberOfCollectionCell %2);

    if(height < self.view.frame.height/2){

 self.collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = kConstantCollectionCellHeight * (numberOfCollectionCell /2 + numberOfCollectionCell %2);   //(Make sure height constant manage properly coz here you are managing items in the collectionView so there are two items at each row)

         [self.yourCollectionView layoutIfNeeded];
         [self.yourCollectionView setNeedsLayout];

    }else{
self.collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant = self.view.frame.height/2;   //(Make sure height constant manage properly coz here you are managing items in the collectionView so there are two items at each row)

         [self.yourCollectionView layoutIfNeeded];
         [self.yourCollectionView setNeedsLayout];

    }



     }
```

[image]

**Constraint for tableView**

- Leading , trailing , top

**Constraint for collectioView**

- Leading , trailing , bottom , Height

Now give one more constaraint,

- Vertical space in between tableView & collectionView `0`

Now take height constraint outlet from storyboard & manage it.

**No need to manage tableHeight**

Comment: ,i m using auto layout and intially setted equal height and what logic i have to use to fix it done,

Comment: Don't give equal height constraint... instead of that give height constraint to both & tableview height constraint should be greater than equal & collectioview height constarint should less than equal & take outlet from your storybaord to .h file & set `self.tableHeightConstraint.constant = kCellHeight * numberOfCells ` & same for collectionView ,Hope this will help you now.

Comment: could u update where i have to use these constants ,

Comment: I have updated answer, you have to handle condition only for incase of equal height in the same method. okay.

Comment: by ur code u r table view height is not increasing if collection view has 2 items and if in table datasource there s no count i want default size of table, now collection view itmes are going above table view and if there r 2 itmes in collection view empty space still remian in collection view at bottom

Comment: your code is not at all working, really empty space in collection remain if two itmes are there in collection view and height of table view does not increase at all,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136724/discussion-between-mukesh-and-imran).

Answer (score 0):

UICollectionView and UITableView are subviews of UIScrollView, you can use setContentOffset to do this.

First, add a observer to get the collectionView's contentOffset. Then, use 
setContentOffset to the tableView.